# Android sariparr validation library , is it possible to compare two edit text to validate one is smaller than the other

Tags: android

I am using the Saripaar validation library https://github.com/ragunathjawahar/android-saripaar and I want to validate two edit text FromAge and ToAge, I want to show error message if FromAge is larger than ToAge but I can't make it work so is this possible with the library?

Comment: can you please add an example ? by larger you mean the number of characters ? the period ?

Comment: The user will specify range of age like from 20 to 25 , i want to validate  that input FromAge (20) is smaller than ToAge(25)

Comment: @amrsalah if it is "that kind of" application; simply offer age-ranges.

Comment: @MartinZeitler This is just an example , Im trying to find a validation library for android that is customizable where I can put complex validation rules but i can't find a way to do the example above with the library

Answer (score 0):

You do it like this

```
int fromAge = Integer.parseInt(FromAge.getText().toString()); // get data from EditText and cast it to integer
int toAge = Integer.parseInt(ToAge.getText().toString());
if(fromAge> toAge){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Your Message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

don't forget to set your `EditText` input type to number

```
android:inputType="number"
```